# mysql: Find first father by single query in father son relation table

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a relational table of father and son id, this is many to many relational table and the id of user stored in user table,the basic format of table goes here:

`..........................
|  father_id  |   son_id  |
...........................
|      A      |     B    |
..........................
|      B      |     C    |
..........................
|      C      |     D    |
..........................
|      D      |     E    |`

Now I have to find greatest grand father of any one of the son, can I achieve this by single MySQL query or I have to use PHP loops?

Comment: Mysql is not good dealing with recursive query, however if the depth of the relation is known then using a single query you can travel to and fro. On the other hand you can use a PHP recursive function to get the job done easily.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, so its not possible with MySQL

Comment: "Greatest great grandfather" doesn't mean anything. If you want the *great great grandfather*, then "the depth of the relation is known" and the query is simple. (Otherwise see [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161).) But "of any one of the son" is not clear. Use small, clear sentences and phrases. Do not settle for something unclear; keep editing. Do you want the father_id of every father who is a great grandfather?

Comment: depth of relation is unknown, because we have to find father_id until the last son has no father_id

Comment: Edit your question to *say clearly what your query is supposed to return*. "find father_id until the last son has no father_id" still doesn't mean anything. Do you mean you want pairs of father_ids and son_ids where the father_id is the earliest ancestor of the son_id? Do you want the father_id and son_id pair where the number of generations between the father_id and son_id is the largest? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but if you want the father_id of every father who is a great grandfather:

Your table is rows where "person [father_id] is the father of person [son_id]". Write this in shorthand as is_father_of(father_id,son_id). Notice that the shorthand is like an SQL table declaration. Alias fs,gs,ggs to your original table is_father_of. You want rows (ggs.is_father_id) where

```
    is_father_of(fs.father_id,fs.son_id)
and is_father_of(gs.father_id,fs.father_id)
and is_father_of(ggs.father_id,gs.father_id)
```

This is

```
select gg.is_father_id
from is_father_of fs
join is_father_of gs on gs.son_id = fs.father_id
join is_father_of ggs on ggs.son_id = gs.father_id
```